# Как прочитать / записать значение переменных js в файл?

Tags: javascript

Возможно это очень странно, но ситуация такая.
Я решил сделать игры типа кликер в android studio, на html, css, js.
Все было хорошо, до тех пор пока я вспомнил про сохранения.
Как можно сохранить значение переменной js в файл и потом считать, не прибегая к Java?

Comment: наверно node.js потребуется ...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB